# Laravel postcode lookups

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, geolocation, location, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to add an address lookup to a few forms, where the user can enter a UK postcode and house number and then the other address lines are auto-filled.

I've turned up one or two potentially promising things on Github but they're pretty old and lack really clear, dumbed-down instructions (I'm a Laravel / MVC / OOPHP noob so really need it spelled out).

I'd be open to something API-based that connects to a paid or free service, or alternatively I'm not opposed to downloading the postcode database to host locally if that's better.

If it's something anyone has done with Laravel recently, I'd really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Also looking for this!

Answer (score 1):

I've produced a JavaScript solution for this which is built on the [Ideal-Postcodes.co.uk](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk) API. This can be accomplished using an external library and a dozen lines of JavaScript

```
IdealPostcodes.PostcodeLookup.setup({
  context: "#lookup_field",
  apiKey: 'iddqd',
  strictlyPostcodes: false,
  placeholder: "Search for a postcode or address",
  selectSinglePremise: true,
  outputFields: {
    line_1: '#first_line',
    line_2: '#second_line',
    line_3: '#third_line',
    post_town: '#post_town',
    postcode: '#postcode'
  }
});
```

Some links to get you started:

- [Live version of the above example](https://jsfiddle.net/ideal_postcodes/vgk3oxm2)
- [Additional demos if you would like to customise](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/postcode-lookup-demo)
- [Postcode Lookup JavaScript library](https://github.com/ideal-postcodes/postcode-lookup-bundled)

The data is based on a commercial service however and requires an API Key.